# Is proper documentation on .xef files available anywhere?

Tags: encryption, file-encryption

WinACE encrypts files (using one of its 8 methods) into a file with the extension .xef. I'd want to see some documentation on this file format but I couldn't find anything...

I'm particularly interested to know:

- How the file is stored
- Which of the eight encryption algorithms it actually used to create the file
- What key it used (128-bit, 160-bit, 256-bit, etc.)

How can that information be retrieved from the file?

Answer (score 2):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACE_%28file_format%29):

> Packing of ACE files is licensed as proprietary information and only available through WinACE, while Unpacking of ACE files is supported by a number of third-party archivers. **However, virtually all of them (the ones that support ACE 2.x format) do this by using the proprietary "Unace.dll" from e-merge GmbH.**

In the [WinACE site](http://www.winace.com/licence.html) you can read that using that .DLL you have:

> The downloadable distribution of UnACE.DLL contains the 32bit .DLL, a list of function calls as well as some function prototypes, structures and constants to include when using the .DLL.

So, perhaps using it you can retrieve those informations.

Comment: So basically you suggest I reverse engineer a bit that `unace.dll`?

Comment: First, you could ask the WinACE developers if they would like to give you that information. If they don't get you what you need, *and it's allowed by the laws where you do live*, you could try reverse engineer.